# Trouble installing nano

Tags: apt, nano

I have a docker container running debian linux (it's using the postgres image) that I'd like to install nano on so I can edit files. However, when I try

```
# apt-get install nano
```

the output I get is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nano
```

I am following [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nano). What step am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So apparently there was an easy solution to this. I just needed to update first:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install nano
```

Comment: Please, say, why before "apt-get install nano" you should do "apt-get update"?